# Natural Ergonomic Keyboard 4000

Tags: keyboard, cleaning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tips for getting latte or soda out of your keyboard? (Microsoft Ergonomic Keyboard 4000)](https://superuser.com/questions/16306/tips-for-getting-latte-or-soda-out-of-your-keyboard-microsoft-ergonomic-keyboar)

Spilled a glass of tea on my keyboard.  The  key does not work nor does the sound button to lower volume.  any ideas?  Hate to toss it, but I've dried it out for 2 days with direct air on it with the keys off and it hasn't helped.
thanks

Answer (score 3):

Some people report success with dishwashers (I'd advise no detergent, but [this](http://plasticbugs.com/?p=263) guy apparently was ok with Electrasol), I think personally I'd try a squeeze bottle like in Chemistry 101 with distilled water to get at the goo left in there.  Essentially, you're *probably* safe rinsing it with distilled water when it's disconnected from power, but there are obviously no guarantees.  The other thing to check is this:  is the problem with the volume key 'physical'?  That is, is it residue in there or has something actually shorted it out?  If the action of the key is 100% fine, you might suspect the latter, unfortunately. But like @Wil said, if there's nothing to lose, you may as well do what you can to see if your keyboard can live again.

Answer (score 1):

If all else is lost, take it outside and get a garden hose / pressure washer (on a low setting), and simply put as much water as you can over it to get rid of all tea residue...

If possible, take off the keys (with the exception of space, enter and any other big ones that are awkward to put back) before doing it.

I have had quite a lot of success with this, the idea is to wash as much as possible to get it completely clean... Then let it dry out fully.

Hopefully it will work for you!

Answer (score 1):

Have you opened it up and cleaned it inside?