# Can I - and should I - rinse my mechanical keyboard after spillage?

Tags: keyboard, cleaning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tips for getting latte or soda out of your keyboard?](https://superuser.com/questions/16306/tips-for-getting-latte-or-soda-out-of-your-keyboard)

Unfortunate incident at work today whereby, whilst laughing, I managed to elbow a mug of tea (one sugar!) on to my [ThermalTake eSports Meka G1](http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B0059KCWJ8/) keyboard. About a quarter of it "penetrated".

I turned it over then after a few minutes patted it dry. At first glance it appeared to work fine.

However, since coming back to it a few hours later, the "h" key now types "hn" and the "n" key now types "hn". Space bar is inconsistent and occasionally types a line return too.

I've read that you can actually wash keyboards. Should I do that? Simply dip it in a bowl of soapy water then let it dry out overnight?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: First, leave it long enough to dry. A couple of minutes is useless.

Comment: Little bit late for that now, @Xavierjazz, but thanks anyway :)

Comment: no way, you should put more coffee and cake on it!

Answer (score 1):

You're getting extra characters typed (among other things) because the water is still conducting electricity through the contacts under the keys.

Personally, I would open the keyboard and remove each layer of the device: keys (integrated or individual), the keyboard mold (top and bottom), contact sheet, and circuit board.

I would wash the mold, keys and contact sheet with dish soap to get any liquid/sugar off.

I'd also wipe down the circuit board with a wet cloth.

Let all the parts air dry completely before reassembling.

Comment: no problem.  good luck.

Comment: Just stressing one thing: Let all the parts air dry **completely** before reassembling.

Comment: I'll do it over the weekend @Hennes. 24 hours in ~20c house should suffice yes?

Comment: In normal conditions and near the heating: probably more than long enough. If you live in the tropic during the monsoon (extra moist air): probably not.