# How to reassemble space bar (logitech mx keys | scissors switch)

Tags: keyboard, logitech-keyboard

[image]

This Logitech Mx Keys keyboard I bought 2 days ago. Today I spilled quite a bit of coffee on it..

I took off the space bar key to clean any coffee residue, and now I don't know how to put it back on correctly. If I simply clip the bar straight on, there is no "push" to it and it is just stuck in place.

All the right places which need to be clicked in get clicked in but I must be doing something wrong. I think its the positioning of the metal bars when u click it in on or something like that, Hence the metal bars rotate, should they be crossed or at an angle on placement? Please help me..

Comment: [The author of this question, answered your question, in their question body.](https://superuser.com/questions/16306/tips-for-getting-latte-or-soda-out-of-your-keyboard).  I only link to it in hopes it might help.

Comment: @Ramhound im scared i broke it by taking it off, in the sense its not suppose to be taken off, what do you think?

Comment: It was designed to be removed.

Comment: @Ramhound is it weird that by lifting the space bar with a screw driver in all sides more and more it is slowly getting back to its original feel and push and not stuck :0

Comment: @coders I highly recommender using a spudger or an old credit card or similar rather than a screwdriver. This allows you to much more gentle on the underlying parts. (Also you can use multiple cards to hold things that are partially unclipped before the final release)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you sorted this. But you just need to make sure its orientated properly and then press down firmly on all of the edges (not over the clip itself) there are little notches that click around the two metal bars (top and bottom) that make an audible click when they go back in place.

Press firmly.

Good luck, I did the same thing, except somehow I lost a part of my scissor clip so now my spacebar operates on only one scissor clip but seems to work perfectly fine at this stage.