# How to effectively clean a keyboard

Tags: keyboard, cleaning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to clean a keyboard](https://superuser.com/questions/1331/how-to-clean-a-keyboard)

My keyboard used to look so clean and shiny (when I bought it). Now it looks dull, old, dusty.

How do I clean between the buttons and is there a way to bring back the glossy effect.

What additional precautions should I take ?

My Keyboard:

[image]

Comment: Your question has been closed as a duplicate, see the link at the top of your question and see if it does answer your question. If not, please adjust your question and mention why it does not answer your question and flag your question for attention so that we can reopen it...