# How can I disable my laptop's built-in keyboard in Windows 7?

Tags: laptop, keyboard, drivers

I have a HP Compaq Presario C700 laptop with Windows 7 installed on it.

My laptop's keyboard is not working properly; some keys never work and some keys will keep on pressing. I've formatted the OS but it didn't solve my problem.

I bought an external USB keyboard and it works well. As some keys in the built-in keyboard activate themselves, I still couldn't work effectively.

After searching Google I tried the following steps to disable the built-in keyboard:

1. **Disabled keyboard drivers:**
   This didn't work because when the system reboots, the driver gets installed again automatically.
2. **Installed irrelevant driver for keyboard:**
   This failed - I couldn't install the driver. After rebooting it installed the correct driver automatically.

Can anyone help explain how I can temporarily uninstall my built-in keyboard? I don't want to remove it manually (removing the hardware cable).

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the keyboard? http://superuser.com/questions/1331/how-to-clean-a-keyboard

Comment: Disable automatic driver installation: http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/how-to-disable-automatic-driver-installation-in-windows-vista/

Comment: @kedar, Thanks kedar, i think this may help, will try this and give you a feedback

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick I tried to clean with vaccum cleaner, it didn't help. There is no dust in it.

Comment: Never use a vacuum cleaner on a laptop - the static can break things!

Comment: You say you disabled the keyboard drivers but it sounds like you uninstalled them. Can you unplug your USB keyboard, start **device manager**, find **keyboards** and right-click - **disable** them all, then plug back in your USB keyboard?

Comment: @ Yeodave : ok will try and tell you!!

Comment: You've damaged the keyboard. Your wants to disable the keyboard... But you can also replace the laptop keyboard. If you ran your laptop too hot (bitcoin mining) the heat will kill your keyboard. And the obvious things like spills can kill the keyboard too.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Look at [this article](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/how-to-disable-automatic-driver-installation-in-windows-vista/), it will help you to disable your laptop keyboard by uninstalling your keyboard driver.

> - Go to Start–>Search type in gpedit.msc
> - Click the file to open the Local Group Policy Editor and show Windows who is in control!! You want to go here: Computer
>     Configuration->Administrative Templates->System->Device Installation.
>     Click on the subfolder Device Installation Restrictions on the left and on the
>     right side you will see the possible restrictions.
> - Right Click on Prevent Installation of Devices not described by other policy settings and edit this option, set it on ENABLED.
> - Reboot Windows and enjoy its inability to pollute your system with its standard driver, open gpedit.msc again and revert the change so
>     you will be able to install your driver.

Comment: Note GPEDIT is only available in Pro and up versions of Windows.

Comment: On Windows home edition no group policies. The alternative workaround that worked for me is updating device driver and choosing some wrong driver.

Comment: Using the method in this answer prevents plug-and-play from working properly for other devices. It is better to find out your device Hardware ID in the Device Manager. Copy this ID and then instead if "Prevent installation of devices not described by other policy settings", you should enable "Prevent installation of devices that match any of these device IDs".  Click on the "Show" button. Paste the device ID in the empty field. Check "Also apply to matching devices that are already installed." and reboot for the changes to take effect.

Comment: It will block other drivers installation, so its not feasible solution. e.g if you connect phone it wont detect it.

Answer (score 4):

For laptop Asus X82S using Windows XP, I was successful using these steps

Please go to `C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\...`. You will see some files start with kb, change `kbfiltr` to `kbfiltr_del`. And you will have done it.

This will disable laptop keyboard. At the moment, I use USB keyboard. And no problems for keys anymore.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not familiar enough with this machine to tell you how easy it is, but generally the keyboard on a machine like this is end-user replaceable, so you could simply replace it.  Alternatively, you could just open the machine and unplug the data cable connecting it to the motherboard.  (I suggest this way specifically so that it doesn't cause you grief in the BIOS or something like that, if the occasion arises.)

Comment: i don't need to remove my machine . Any other way??

Comment: @sam - I have no idea what you're trying to ask.  "Remove my machine"?

Comment: i don't need to remove my laptop manually and remove the keyboard's harware cable. Another another way other than this?

Comment: It's the best way to do it - if you're afraid to open it, I don't know what to tell you.

Comment: Also, it sounds like you don't speak English natively, so I'm not sure I understand you correctly, but it sounds like you're trying to say that you would prefer not to do this.  If I read you word for word it sounds like you mean you're physically incapable of it for some reason - if that's the case please say so.

Comment: ok shinrai, as i have not opened my lap before, i am afraid of opening my lap..

Comment: It looks like on the Presario C700 you only have to remove three screws.  See the maintenance guide here - http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c01301275.pdf

Answer (score 3):

Installing the wrong driver for the laptop keyboard, as outlined here worked for me: https://superuser.com/a/788372/7018

Answer (score 2):

In case you can't access gpedit.msc (group policy), what you can do is, uninstall the standard keyboard driver from device manager and don't restart the computer. Just sign out and log back in. You'll see your inbuilt keyboard won't be working. 
Tested on my Windows 10 Home Edition 1607, and it works fine. Now, I can safely put my external keyboard on the laptop's keyboard and not worry about the keys anymore.
Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks Shanks :) You saved my life.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to disable a specific builtin keyboard with registry:

1. In Device manager, select Properties for the keyboard in question.
2. Go to Details.
3. Select "Device Instance path" from the list.
4. Note the string, it will be used later.
5. Download SysInternals psexec
6. Run `psexec /s /i regedit` - this is because even Administrators can't modify these registry settings
7. Navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum`
8. Further navigate according to string from step 4.
9. Change the value of `ConfigFlags` to `1`.
10. Reboot.
11. When you want to enable keyboard again, change the value of `ConfigFlags` to `0`.

Comment: My laptop has the power button at one corner along with the other keys. Won't this method affect the power button as well?

Comment: I don't know. You can try and report your findings here.

Comment: Worthless idea. Device won't even boot thereafter :|

Answer (score 0):

Installing a proper driver through device manager worked fine for me.

I have an acer. All I did was click the option which let me choose from a list of drivers. I installed a toshiba japanese driver and shutdown the laptop. When started back up, the keyboard did not work at all. (P.S.: I did not restart; I shut it down.)

Answer (score 0):

My try on Windows10.
1. Open **Device Manager**, right click **Standard PS/2 Keyboard**, select **Properties**, select tab **Driver**, click **Driver Details** and you can see a list of three Driver files.
On my laptop, there're:
**C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\i8042prt.sys**
 **C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\kbdclass.sys**
**C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\SynTP.sys**
In my exploration, **i8042prt.sys** is my laptop keyboard's driver together with touchpad, **kbdclass.sys** is general keyboard driver and **SynTP.sys** is touchpad driver. Disabling laptop keyboard is also disabling laptop touchpad.
2. In my case, I need to rename **C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\i8042prt.sys**, find the driver file, right click **driver file**, select **Properties**, select tab **Security**, click **Advanced**, click **Change**, type **YOUR_USERNAME**, click **OK**, click **OK**, click **OK**, right click **driver file**, select **Properties**, select tab **Security**, click **Advanced**, click **Add**, click **Select a principal**, type **YOUR_USERNAME**, click **OK**, checked **Full control**, click **OK**, click **OK**, click **Yes**, click **OK**.
Now you can rename the **driver file**, I renamed it to **i8042prt.sys_bak**.
3. Reboot.

Answer (score -1):

I solved my similar problem by clicking Start>Devices and Printers, then clicking on the icon for the computer and clicking the Hardware tab in the Properties dialog. Then I double-clicked the keyboard entry to open the Driver Properties dialog and clicked the Change Settings button, which should require administrator privileges. Once that dialog opens, click the Driver tab, and the option to disable the driver should be available. Click disable and bingo, laptop keyboard all gone away. Make sure you have you USB keyboard installed properly first.

Worked first time for me.