# My laptop's touchpad is not working

Tags: keyboard, drivers, mouse

I had posted a question long back and got answer for it.

Refer : [How can I disable my laptop's built-in keyboard in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/346570/how-can-i-disable-my-laptops-built-in-keyboard)

My Question was, How can i disable my Laptop Keyboard!. I got Answer and Disabled it, But Disabling my Keyboard, disabled my laptop mouse(TouchPad) also,

Can i know how can i enable my mouse(TouchPad). I tried all the way to install drivers for laptop mouse(TouchPad), But i couldn't finish installing driver. It shows error.

Help Needed.!!

Comment: do you mean the laptop touchpad ?

Comment: Yes shark. i Mean my Laptop Touch Pad!!!

Comment: what's the error that you get ?

Answer (score 0):

First off, not sure why you would disable a laptop keyboard (yes.. I read your initial question).

But its better to seek a hardware replacement than trying to isolate the issue with a software 'block'.  I'm not sure why you are complaining now, you have succeeded in blocking your keyboard, and your touchpad which most likely combines with you keyboard driver set, is not working as a result.

I would find a keyboard replacement (ebay?), usually laptop keyboards pop in and out for replacement.

Here is an amazon link for instance to a new keyboard:
[image]
[http://www.amazon.com/HP-Presario-Keyboard-454954-001-PK1302E0200/dp/B003O7GLSG](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003O7GLSG)

I would suggest that, as playing around and blocking policy for drivers and disabling built in keyboards will just bring you back to this type of trouble.

Comment: Thanks Jakub, But i have bought an external Keyboard. As i used to handle my keyboard rough for playing games i prefer External keyboard. Can i be able to install my Touch pad driver alone?

Comment: can you please tell me how can i install my touchpad driver alone.. Is it possible?

Comment: @sam, no, I'm not sure, typically people don't disable their laptop keyboards because they don't want to fix the hardware problem.