# Disable Asus N56VJ internal keyboard

Tags: drivers, keyboard

Is there a way to disable the internal keyboard for a laptop. It's broken currently and I have an external keyboard.

I have already tried disabling it in device manager ( no effect ) and tried editing the group policy (gpedit.msc) to no avail. Any other solutions?

Comment: Hardware solution: disconnect it, as shown in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VC_GLPNtn2I or http://www.laptopkeyboard.com/Guides.php/Asus/N%20Series/N56VJ/KBA55N. BTW, a keyboard at Amazon or NewEgg is ~US$ 25-30.

Comment: You might want to uninstall the keyboard driver instead of disabling it. See http://superuser.com/questions/346570/how-can-i-disable-my-laptops-built-in-keyboard-in-windows-7