# Is there any way to disable laptop's keyboard on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard

I have acer laptop with broken keyboard, so I am using an external USB keyboard. Can I disable PC's keyboard for all time? I have tried to physically damage keyboard.

Comment: Disconnect the internal keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

Try out this link...

http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/id-2753989/disable-keyboard-windows.html

and afterwards this one;

[How can I disable my laptop's built-in keyboard in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/346570/how-can-i-disable-my-laptops-built-in-keyboard-in-windows-7)

I hope this helps!! :)