# How should I clean and restore an old Apple II computer?

Tags: restore, cleaning, apple-ii

Wondering what I should know before I start tearing this thing down to clean it. What's a good way to clean and restore it in a safe manner? Especially the keyboard as many keys take many tries to finally work.

The video worked with an old TV :)

[image]

wrote a program :P

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to clean a keyboard](http://superuser.com/questions/1331/how-to-clean-a-keyboard) also see: [How do I clean dust from a computer?](http://superuser.com/questions/775/how-do-i-clean-dust-from-a-computer?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

A UK based company called Scrumpy Macs specialises in quality used & refurbished Apple Macs. They also buy refurbs from individuals.It might be worth contacting them by email for advice regarding your old Apple II. I'm sure they will be more than happy to help or advise as appropriate.

http://www.scrumpymacs.co.uk/