# Mac OS X Terminal and iTerm2 cannot type '.' or '/'

Tags: macos, bash, keyboard, terminal, iterm2

As the title says, I'm unable to type the characters `.` and `/` in terminal.  <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> results in `>` and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>results in `?`, which means the keys actually work.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Was using zsh, figured out right arrow key was stuck on

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to clean a keyboard](http://superuser.com/questions/1331/how-to-clean-a-keyboard)

Answer (score 2):

My dumb ass spilled beer on the keyboard and now the right arrow is stuck on. It would seem as the right arrow key, dot and forward slash are on the same circuit, so holding the right arrow key down does not allow you to type dot and forward slash anymore....

Comment: I suspect this belongs on your question - its a cause of the issue, not the solution.