# Right ctrl-alt-del works but not Left ctrl-alt-del for Lenovo Thinkpad W520

Tags: keyboard, thinkpad, lenovo-laptop, ctrl-alt-delete

I just received a Lenovo Thinkpad W520 and at the login screen left ctrl-alt-del won't work for me but the right ctrl-alt-del will.  I have no idea of the history of this particular computer.  Is there a setting which I could undo to allow left ctrl-alt-del to work again, or is this a sign of a well-worn computer/laptop, or what can I do to restore the combo I am so used to?

Comment: Do other left+ctrl combinations work as expected? Like ctrl+c, ctrl+v etc?

Comment: Sounds like that left CTRL or ALT key is broken.  Have you confirmed they work?

Comment: @DavidPostill Actually, it is the same for cut/paste it looks like.  Right ctrl-c and ctrl-v work left ctrl-c and left ctrl-v do not work.

Comment: Try some of the suggestions in [How to clean a keyboard](http://superuser.com/q/1331) to clean underneath the left ctrl key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps in BIOS the Fn and Ctrl keys have been swapped. Try Fn instead of Ctrl and if that works you may want to unswap them in the BIOS.

Comment: Hmm, I guess that might be it after all.  Fn does work as I would expect left ctrl to.  Haven't tried going into BIOS yet, but I will get to that at the next available reboot.

Comment: Sorry, I should have done better with this one.  Yes in the BIOS it was enabled the fn and ctrl swap.  Why, it would be still baffles me.  Don't help me solve that one though.