# Some keys on my laptop don't work

Tags: keyboard, toshiba-laptop, satellite

I have a Toshiba Satellite L50-B-1V2 laptop, and some keys don't work on it. It used to be my sister's, and she did abuse it quite a bit, so that is a possibility. All I know for sure is which keys are not functional:
grave accent (beside 1), 1 and 2 (not numpad), tab, W, E, caps lock, A, F, H, K, L, left shift, X, C, V, left control, and Windows.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like a hardware problem. You can see if you can buy a replacement keyboard, or replace the laptop altogether.

Comment: If you plug a regular USB keyboard in, you'll at least still be able to use it. But as @LPChip says, it sounds like your sister gave that thing some abuse!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to clean a keyboard](https://superuser.com/questions/1331/how-to-clean-a-keyboard)

Comment: @spikey_richie Yes, a USB keyboard works perfectly and I use one, but it's a bit clunky and makes the laptop less portable. The only reason I want to fix it is convenience.

Comment: @LPChip Buying a replacement keyboard is an option, I saw a reasonably priced one. However, it is a bit risky because the thing is riveted to the mobo and is inaccessible from the back.

Comment: You can always use an external keyboard... but if you want to salvage your laptop, you will have to get the keyboard replaced one way or the other. Maybe you can find a shop that can do it for you.

Comment: @LPChip After cleaning, breaking many retaining clips and ultimately doing nothing, a replacement seems like the best option. Unil then, I'll make do with speech recognition and the on-screen keyboard.